# What is //= in Perl?

Tags: perl

I found an example of some Perl code I needed, but it had something in it that I didn't recognise.

```
my $i //= '08';
```

I can't find any reference to this anywhere! It appears to be the same as:

```
my $i = '08';
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check [`man perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)? That's usually the first place to look for Perl operators.

Comment: To be fair, perlop doesn't say what it does, only lists its precedence and lets you draw the conclusion that it's `$foo = $foo // $bar`

Comment: This must be a secret Perl operator because I can't find it searching on Google. Or Perl documentation is very poor.

Comment: @Wooble, Actually, it does. See "Assignment Operators", which defines it in terms of `//`, which is defined in "Logical Defined-Or".

Comment: I am now curious if it is possible to search for such things as "//=" in Google. Clearly it's out there - just not searchable. Unless...

Comment: @Upland With Google, it's difficult. But try out [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=perl+%2F%2F%3D). It's made exactly for that purpose. And sorry for answering that late. ;-)

Comment: This operator is in the O'Reilly book, p.124 (4th ed).  Basically it makes the assignment if and only if the target is UNDEF.  See the // operator also (p.119).  Incidentally I found this question by searching for "perl operator defined or".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `//=` operator is the [assignment operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) version of the `//` or ['logical defined-or'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator.

In the context of a `my` variable declaration, the variable is initially undefined so it *is* equivalent to assignment (and would be better written as `my $i = '08';`).  In general, though,

```
$i //= '08';
```

is a shorthand for:

```
$i = (defined $i) ? $i : '08';
```

It is documented in the Perl operators (`perldoc perlop`) in two places (tersely under the assignment operators section, and in full in the section on 'logical defined-or'). It was added in Perl 5.10.0.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I seem to have lived my life ignorant of this until today.  I first checked the camel book .. then Google .. and found nothing. But now I know .. thanks again

Comment: Are you really going to use undocumented operators in your code??

Comment: @tecnotron: Which undocumented operator are you referring to?

Comment: The operator that generated this question, of course ( //= ). But I am saying it to @Upland.

Comment: @tecnotron: I provided references to the documentation for the operator in the current Perl version.  If you're using Perl 5.8.x (or, perish the thought, something older), then it is not available and hence undocumented.  But it was added in Perl 5.10.0 and is available in later versions too.

Comment: Btw called null coalesce operator in php, c# and javascript, analogy. And used by this syntax - two question marks "??" instead of two forward slashes "//"

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: It's the same as `my $i = '08';`. You probably wanted `$i //= '08';`.

---

First, let's look at `$i //= '08';`

```
EXPR1 //= EXPR2;
```

is the same as

```
EXPR1 = EXPR1 // EXPR2;
```

except that EXPR1 is only evaluated once. It's a convenient way of writing

```
EXPR1 = EXPR2 if !defined(EXPR1);
```

See [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for documentation on Perl operators.

---

Back to `my $i //= '08';`. That means

```
my $i;
$i = '08' if !defined($i);
```

but `$i` will always be undefined in that situation. It would be far better to write

```
my $i = '08';
```

But, the code was probably supposed to be

```
$i //= '08';   # no `my`
```

Answer (score 6):

It is "defined-or" operator.

```
$i //= '08';
```

is equivalent to:

```
$i = defined($i)? $i: '08';
```

It was introduced in Perl 5.10.0, and not supported by older versions.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about `**my** $i //= ...;`

Comment: the question is posted as "What is //= in perl?"

Answer (score 5):

`$i //= '08'` is the same as `$i = defined($i) ? $i : '08'`.
It's almost the same as `$i ||= '08'`, which translates to `$i = $i ? $i : '08'`.
Now, when you declare your variable with `my`, it's set to `undef`. Thus, it will always follow the `08` branch.
Also, in case you're wondering, the `//` operator appeared in the Perl v5.10; so it would generate a compilation error on the older Perls.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost the same as `||`, except that it checks if `$i` is defined, not just true.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about `**my** $i //= ...;`

Comment: Could we call it for the case of simplified illustration a 'null coalesce' operator?