# What does // and //= do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I am still trying to learn the syntax of it. I have seen someone using `//` and `//=` in Perl but I couldn't find any resources on the web that explain this.

Can someone explain to me what exactly does it mean in layman terms? And what it actually does?

Comment: [logical defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or)

Comment: Why the close votes. The perldoc entry lacks the usual lucidity and its not really clear what the operator does or why you would use it. In particular the short form "//=" is not documented at all.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: You are not right. There is documentation for both [`//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) and [`//=`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) and it is pretty clear what it does. *except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is //= in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846676/what-is-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or):

> #### Logical Defined-Or
>
> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's `//` operator is related to its C-style or. In fact, it's exactly the same as `||`, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth. Thus, `EXPR1 // EXPR2` returns the value of `EXPR1` if it's defined, otherwise, the value of `EXPR2` is returned. (`EXPR1` is evaluated in scalar context, `EXPR2` in the context of `//` itself). Usually, this is the same result as `defined(EXPR1) ? EXPR1 : EXPR2` (except that the ternary-operator form can be used as a lvalue, while `EXPR1 // EXPR2`cannot). This is very useful for providing default values for variables. If you actually want to test if at least one of `$a` and `$b` is defined, use `defined($a // $b)`.

So:

```
 $NODEFINED // $DEFINED # will return the value of defined

 $DEFINED1 // $DEFINED2 # will return the value of $DEFINED1

 $a //= $b;
```

is shorthand for:

```
 $a = $a // $b;
```

So `$a` will be set to the value `$b` ONLY if `$a` is undefined.

The `$a //= 42;` form is useful for setting a default for a variable that may not yet be defined.

Answer (score 7):

As kjprice mentioned, `//` is the logical 'defined or' operator and [is documented here on the perlop page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) and the relevant excerpt is

> it's exactly the same as ||, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth. Thus, EXPR1 // EXPR2 returns the value of EXPR1 if it's defined, otherwise, the value of EXPR2 is returned.

You can think of

```
my $var = EXPR1 // EXPR2;
```

as a short hand way of writing:

```
my $var;
if ( defined EXPR1 ) {
    $var = EXPR1;
} else {
    $var = EXPR2;
}
```

I often use this to either assign a default value to a variable unless a supplied by command line or config file value is supplied.  Something like:

```
my $var = $config_version // 'foo';
```

The `//=` is a variation of this with an assignemnt mixed in.  That same perlop page says this:

> Modifying an assignment is equivalent to doing the assignment and then
>   modifying the variable that was assigned to.

For `//=` that means instead of writing something like

```
my $var = EXPR1 // EXPR2;
```

You could write

```
my $var = EXPR1;
$var //= EXPR2;
```

and get equivalent values.