# Why does Perl string become undefined?

Tags: string, perl

What is the proper way to concatenate several scalar values into one Perl string?

The following code is deliberately a series of statements for debugging reasons.

```
my $bill_record;

$bill_record = $acct_no . " |";

$bill_record = $bill_record . defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"})  ?  $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"} : " "  . " |" ;

$bill_record = $bill_record . defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_str"}) ? $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_str"} : " " . " |" ;

$bill_record = $bill_record . defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_apt"}) ? $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_apt"} : " " . " |"  ;

$bill_record = $bill_record . $issue_date . " |";
```

The `|` character is serving as a delimiter. Each line will be `'\n` terminated.

After the last line `$bill_record = $bill_record . $issue_date . " |";` 
This error appears:

```
Use of uninitialized value $bill_record in concatenation (.) or string at /home/ics/include/WsBillFunc.pm line 1022.
 at /home/ics/include/WsBillFunc.pm line 1022
```

`$issue_date` is defined when assigned.

What could be causing `$bill_record` to become undefined, and what is the proper way to concatenate a bunch of scalar values into one string?

Comment: First of all using `$bill_record .= ...` instead of `$bill_record = $bill_record . ...` would make it easier to read.  Also, I would add in enough parens so that the order of operations was obvious.

Comment: @woolstar Fine That works, but why? I thought taking the original scalar `$bill_record` and using `.` would also work.

Comment: Might also be cleaner to build an array and then `join(' |', ...)` it, IMO that matches your intent better than a bunch of string concatenation.

Comment: You should probably look up the [`//=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846676/what-is-in-perl/13846737#13846737) operator (and its relative, `//`), as well as `.=`.  They allow you to write: `$bill_record .= ($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"} // " ") . " |";`, which is a heap easier to read than the expression that scrolls over the RHS of the page.  That does assume you have at least Perl 5.10, IIRC; but you should be using 5.18 anyway by now (or perhaps 5.16 if you've got a retrograde O/S, like Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks, which ships 5.16.2).

Comment: Something you said isn't true. Either that's not your code or `$issue_date` is undefined when that message is issued.

Comment: @ikegami Both things I said were true. There was a problem with operator precedence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know specifically why `$bill_record` is undefined.  But if I understand what you're trying to do, you're running into a precedence problem: the `?:` operator has lower precedence than concatenation `.`, so that

```
$bill_record = $bill_record . defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"})  ?  $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"} : " "  . " |" ;
```

is treated as

```
$bill_record = ($bill_record . defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"}))  ?  $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"} : (" "  . " |") ;
```

which I suspect is not what you want.  Try adding parentheses:

```
$bill_record = $bill_record . (defined($w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"})  ?  $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef->{"mtr_addr_no"} : " ")  . " |" ;
```

(Or use `.=` as another commenter suggested.)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. I've got to remember to use more parenthesis. In this case, I used the `.=`, but your answer also helps with the why.

Comment: Even with `.=`, you still need parentheses so that the last concatenation, `" " . " |"`, isn't given precedence over the `?:`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do that in one statement with a [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
$bill_record = join ' |',
    map( {
        defined( $_ ) ? $_ : ' '
        } @{ $w_ptWtrMtrRecRef }{ qw( mtr_addr_no mtr_addr_str mtr_addr_apt ) }
        ),
    $issue_date,
    '';
```

In the [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) I limit with parens because I only want to apply it to the hash slice. After that is the `$issue_date` and the empty string. That empty string gets the final `|` you have.

But, for your problem, it looks like you have a precedence problem. One way to see this is to ask Perl to compile then deparse your program to see what it thinks you wanted. The [B::Deparse](http://www.metacpan.org/module/B%3a%3aDeparse) module does this and I use the `-p` argument to add extra parentheses.

Here's a cut down version of your original program with the added call to the deparser at the top (it's the [B::Deparse](http://www.metacpan.org/module/B%3a%3aDeparse) module but the namespace is `O`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use O qw(Deparse -p);

my $b;
$b = $acct_no . " |";
$b = $b . defined($w->{"no"})  ? $w->{"no"}  : " " . " |" ;
$b = $b . defined($w->{"str"}) ? $w->{"str"} : " " . " |" ;
$b = $b . defined($w->{"apt"}) ? $w->{"apt"} : " " . " |"  ;
$b = $b . $issue_date . " |";
```

It outputs:

```
my($b);
($b = ($acct_no . ' |'));
($b = (($b . defined($$w{'no'})) ? $$w{'no'} : '  |'));
($b = (($b . defined($$w{'str'})) ? $$w{'str'} : '  |'));
($b = (($b . defined($$w{'apt'})) ? $$w{'apt'} : '  |'));
($b = (($b . $issue_date) . ' |'));
```

The key part is the `(($b . defined($$w{'no'}))`. The current value of `$b` is concatenated with the return value of [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html), then the conditional operator (`? :`) is done. If the test value is true, it returns the first value in the conditional.

When it gets to `mgr_apt_no`, there are probably many records that don't have that value set. However, the combined value of the previous `$b` and `$$w{'apt'}` is defined because `$b` is not empty. Thus, it chooses the value of `$$w{'apt'}` to assign to `$b`. When it does the last line, `$b` is empty for the concatenation with `$issue_date`.